What is the name of this synth guitar?



Can anyone tell me what the name is of the guitar in this video?

As Tom mentioned they do have strings but they are bendy and very low tension, and as Data_Processing pointed out its a DG-20 and the frets are actually pressure sensors. I assume the bridge has some kind of vibration sensor and when a string is played it sounds the pitch that should correspond to the string and current fret sensor combination. They are very weird to play, and a lot of them these days are clunky and unreliable to get a note because the sensors get old and dirty, but a good one should be pretty sensitive.
However I would contest the statement that they are not fun to play :). Certainly don't expect to be able to extract (anywhere NEAR) a guitar like performance out of them, they don't respond to a lot of guitar type nuance and have quite a significant delay. But linked to a  external synth via MIDI I've found them really fun to quickly put together interesting sounds/parts for a song, primarily with synth pads. They are interesting to use if your guitar playing is stronger than your keyboard playing (as is my case) or just to get you to approach playing a synth in a different way, where different voicings naturally present themself, they've made from some cool parts in songs of some of my old bands.
The one in the video seems pristine, I would imagine that getting/using one these days would be a bit of a labour of love though, once you had restored it to its proper sensitivity level and gotten used to the truly odd feeling strings. You'd almost certainly get the same result but better using a modern midi pickup system. The onboard sounds are just your typical Casio style selection of the keyboards of that era (FM based I think?). If I saw one in a junk shop for £40 I would go for it and expect a bit of fun/pain getting it working, but no more. Probably one of the oddities of an already fairly zany era for electric instruments, and certainly not a classic, but it's uniqueness maybe counts for something to some people (or maybe just me!)

Casio DG-20 (see also DG-10 and DG-1).  Not a guitar at all (no strings), but a synth with a guitar-like plastic button interface.  They are fun to look at but not to play.

Indeed, this is probably this one, but note that the DG-20 actually has strings ;)

If you call those things 'strings'.

Well, yes. I never tried one of those but my gut feeling is that they would feel very different with six switches instead of strings...

Point being, they are basically switches.
